# Component Exception Invalid type

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

I started to learn React-Native a day ago and couldn't resolve my 'Element type is invalid: expected a string' problem. I researched it and couldn't find a solution for my fit. Here is my very simple project:

```
//importing
import React from 'react';
import {Text, AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/components/Header';

//own-typed components
const App = () => (
  <Header/>
);
//rendering
AppRegistry.registerComponent('ORNEKPROJE', () => App);
```

And here is my Header.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

const Header = () => {
  return <Text>Anasayfa</Text>;
};

export default Header;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Try to make `App` component a class component and extend it with `React.Component`. Like this:-

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './src/components/Header';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
   render(){
     return <Header/>
   }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ORNEKPROJE', () => App)
```

Comment: Still can not see my header in the emulator. The emulator is blank completely. In fact, I got the error again.